# Libraries for depositing money into a user's account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, credit-card, currency

I am building an app that needs to take money from a customer who is paying by credit card and deposit that money into another customer's bank account. I don't want to store the bank account info, I just want to say "deposit X dollars into user Y's bank account" where Y calls a 3rd party. The app is in rails. Any clean solutions out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to have the Y's bank routing number and bank account number if you want to directly deposit funds into Y's account.

First you will need to setup Active Merchant in your rails app. Use the plugin or gem:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant.git

gem 'activemerchant'
```

After you got that installed on your app you will need to sign up with a gateway. Heres a full list of supported gateways https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/wiki/gatewayfeaturematrix

These railscasts will get help get you started on Active Merchant:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics

http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant

To use a bank instead of a credit card, create a new method in the Order model if you are following the railscast

```
 def bank_account
  @bank_account ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::Check.new(

   :account_holder_type=> "personal",
   :account_number=>      "number", 
   :account_type =>       "checking/savings", 
   :name=>                "name",
   :routing_number=>      "routing_number")

  end
 end
```

Comment: I am well aware of paypal, but would rather not have users have to sign up for a paypal account. What I want them to be able to do is enter their bank info on my site, I send it to a 3rd party for storage and then call that 3rd party for wheenever I need to deposit into their account.

Comment: well i am not too familiar with Active Merchant but after browsing their documentation it looks like ActiveMerchant has support for just the thing that you are wanting to do. Their is an ActiveMerchant::Billing:Check class which allows you to process payments, or deposit funds using a person's account and routing number. For rails i would suggest looking at the active merchant railscasts to get a better understand of AM. It looks like you can replace the paypal module with the bank module, then use credit to deposit funds into the account.

Comment: is this doable using stripe?

Answer (score 0):

First choose a third party to handle your transactions. And then use their API to do it. For example if you choose PayPal you can use these gems (I have not used them myself, so do check on them before you come to a decision on what to use):

- http://ruby-paypal.rubyforge.org/
- http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/Appx-SDKRuby.html

Comment: I am well aware of paypal, but would rather not have users have to sign up for a paypal account. What I want them to be able to do is enter their bank info on my site, I send it to a 3rd party for storage and then call that 3rd party for wheenever I need to deposit into their account.